# Not able to update the selected option in material UI dropdown

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, drop-down-menu, material-ui

I have below `material ui` code for `select dropdown`, which is not able to update the selected option in dropdown.

```
 <FormControl variant="outlined" className={classes.formControl}>
    <InputLabel ref={inputLabel} htmlFor="outlined-Name">
      Name
    </InputLabel>
    <Select
      value={values.Name}
      onChange={handleBChange}
      labelWidth={labelWidth}
       inputProps={{
       Name: 'Name',
       id: 'outlined-Name',
     }}
  >
  <MenuItem value="">
   <em>None</em>
  </MenuItem>
  <MenuItem value="1">Name1</MenuItem>
  <MenuItem value="2">Name2</MenuItem>
  <MenuItem value="3">Name3</MenuItem>
  </Select>
  </FormControl>
```

and below are the required events and JS.

```
const [values, setValues] = React.useState({
    Name: ''
});


const inputLabel = React.useRef(null);
const [labelWidth, setLabelWidth] = React.useState(0);
React.useEffect(() => {
    setLabelWidth(inputLabel.current.offsetWidth);
}, []);

const handleBChange = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    debugger;
    setValues(oldValues => ({
        ...oldValues,
        [event.target.Name]: event.target.value,
    }));
};
```

What's wrong in my code? Please suggest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to use name not Name as

```
const handleBChange = event => {
event.preventDefault();
setValues(oldValues => ({
    ...oldValues,
    [event.target.name]: event.target.value,
}));
};
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Sorry to inform but still its not updating the value

Comment: Ok, now, i got it, alongwith your code, this also needs to be upadated as  `inputProps={{
                                    name: 'Name',
                                    id: 'outlined-Name',
                                }}`